# Where should a canonical domain name be enforced?

Tags: iis, url, url-rewriting, dns

Our client would like to use just one domain name for their site to prevent diluting page rank in search engines.

For example, stackoverflow.com is the domain name they always use. If you type in www.stackoverflow.com you get redirected to the non-www version, as this is their choice for their domain name.

Where should this be done?

1. At the application server level (ex in IIS, set up a site and have it issue a permanent redirect to the proper domain name
2. At the application level

I don't like #1 as it means I have a bunch of extra sites set up just for redirecting. I don't like #2 as rewrite rules do affect performance.

thanks.

Comment: How can you do #1? I don't think that it's possible.

Comment: You are probably right! I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it at as low a level as you can possibly do it. Your application shouldn't know about its root domain name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying it should be done at the app server (IIS, as a site and 302 redirect for example) or at the application level (.net, in web.config as a url rewrite rule)

Comment: @ScottE: *301* redirect handled by a smart firewall or forward proxy would be your prime option. If that's not an option, use IIS. Here's how to do it in [6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true) and [7.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite familiar with how to set up redirects. FYI - the link for IIS 7 is broken. Also, is this something that can't be done at the DNS level?

Comment: @ScottE -- aah, crap, the link is broken because it had a paren in it, and markdown doesn't deal with them well, and I forgot to url encode it. :( I don't think it's possible to do a full-on redirect at the DNS level, only an alias. I am not an expert on the subject, however, so I may be wrong. If possible, I'd recommend that route as the best one. You might try asking about it over on [server fault](http://serverfault.com).